# How to recognize if element is on the screen using react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

When user scrolling posts in my app i want recognize the current post the user is seeing now.

Comment: are you using `pagingEnabled`

Comment: No, i am using scroll view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get y position on scroll from `contentOffset`

```
<ScrollView
  ref={(s) => this.scrollview = s}
  onScroll={(event) => {console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)}}
  ...
></ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes, but you still did not tell me how recognise which component/element the user see now while he scrolling.

Comment: if all items in scrollview have equal height then `contentOffset.y / itemHeight`. If not equal — sum one by one while they reach your `y`

Comment: Please if you can give me a tiny working example, cause i really still miss something.....  let׳s say if we have the position y of scrollView and we know  the height of post is similar to each post. How do i know that now the user  see the item number seven? , Of course if i calculate it in my head i will know it, but how do i recognise it with react native script while i am scrolling? How do i know to trigger the visible element to user at the moment he see it?

Comment: I think i got your idea now, i will test it and if everything will works well according your suggestion i will accept your answer.

Comment: If i want to the same action with listView, does it the same idea or there is another way?